# Scope of subroutine parameters in FORTRAN 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a subroutine that declares `i` and passes it to other small subroutines. Within those small subroutines there are declared other variables with the same name, i.e `i`, and it is internally used. Once out of the small subroutines, one would expect to have the same `i` value that was originally passed, however that is not the real situation and `i` contains the value of the last parameter assigned within the small subroutines. Here is a brief example:

```
subroutine smallSub1(i)
 integer i,start,end
 start=i
 end = start +10
 do i=start, end
    write(*,*) i
 enddo
end subroutine smallSub1

subroutine caller
integer i
i = 1
call smallSub1(i)
write(*,*) i
end subroutine caller
```

My question is, how could I avoid this behavior in F77?

My concern here is: think about a situation where a subroutine is a black box, and you just need to pass an integer, but you do not want that integer value to change from the `smallSub1` subroutine. The variables `start` and `end` would depend on the value of `i` however they should not replace the original value of `i` out of `smallSub1`

Comment: Three answers so far and not one of them has mentioned use of `intent` to clarify programmer's requirements not just for the compiler's benefit, also for the programmer's.  I know `intent` is post-FORTRAN77 but it is 2015 for Knuth's sake.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, `intent` would be the cleanest solution. But I wanted to know how (and why) it is actually done in the pure F77 world

Comment: @Manolete Your code isn't pure F77: note what looks like free-form and the use of `end do` and a few other things.

Comment: Why would you want to know how to program in pure FORTRAN77 ?  Do you have a DeLorean ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Just out of curiosity

Comment: re: "why would you expect" . Its not such a silly question, anyone coming from a `c` or similar background would expect `i` to be passed by value and remain unchanged to the caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code example given there are two variables `i`: one in each subroutine.  In subroutine `caller` the `i` is a local variable, and in the subroutine `smallSub1` it is a dummy argument.

When you have `call smallSub1(i)` you are associating the two `i` variables with each other through argument association.  In this simple case, then, any change to `i` in `smallSub1` affects the `i` in `caller`.  There is how argument association works here.

Traditionally one did have black-boxes where an argument is changed in the subroutine when that wasn't desired.  Where it is used as a work-space, for example.  In that case, one would do something like

```
inew = i
call smallSub1(inew)
... continue using i
```

In this case, however, one can easily (I imagine) change the subroutine.  Introduce an extra local variable:

```
subroutine smallSub1(i)
  integer i   ! Dummy argument - we don't want to change it
  integer start,end
  integer j   ! Local variable - we're quite free to change it
              ! In general, we'd have j=i at the start and use that instead
  start=i
  end = start +10
  do j=start, end
     write(*,*) j
  enddo
end subroutine smallSub1
```

And with modern Fortran one even has the `value` attribute, which can be applied to the dummy argument allowing one to change it without impact on the actual argument.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the other answer, Fortran typically passes by reference and when that is not possible it does things like copy-in/copy-out.  As said  succinctly by others in comments, if you don't want to change `i` then don't change `i`.

In your subroutine `smallSub1`, `i` is being used as a loop iteration variable and and you don't want its value changes visible to the caller.  The reason changing `i` is visible to `caller` is because `i` isn't a local variable, it is a dummy argument.  The solution is call the loop variable and the dummy argument by different names.  One such solution is:

```
subroutine smallSub1(i_from_caller)
  integer  i,i_from_caller,start,end
  start = i_from_caller
  end = start +10
  do i=start, end
     write (*,*) i
  end do
end subroutine smallSub1
```

In this case the dummy argument has been renamed to `i_from_caller` and is used to initialize `start`.  Now the loop variable `i` is truly local to the subroutine (as it is no longer the name of a dummy argument) and changing `i` here won't change `i` in `caller`

---

To help avoid this kind of behavior you can give the compiler hints that dummy arguments are for input, output or both.  If you had declared `i` as `integer, intent(in) :: i` in `smallSub1` in your original example, the compiler would complain:

```
     do i=start, end
       1
Error: Dummy argument ‘i’ with INTENT(IN) in variable definition context (iterator variable) at (1)
```

making you aware that you are making unwanted changes to a dummy argument.

Answer (score 1):

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html
Fortran passes most arguments by reference

Therefore, if you don't want the variable to change, don't change it in the subroutine. You are allowed to rename the variable smallSub1(i) to smallSub1(j)
you don't want to change the entire function.

Comment: Renaming the dummy argument isn't going to change the behaviour of the program.  I think I know what you mean but I think OP might need a clearer explanation

Comment: My guess is that he is using one variable, when two are needed. One for the value of start, and another for the loop i. Maybe he should change the argument to start and forget save a step of assigning it.

Comment: Indeed.  I suspect that confusion comes about from thinking that the dummy argument is in some way local to the subroutine.  But then, expecting the value to also be useful as input contradicts that.  [So I agree that we need more information to understand what is the difficult part.]